# Select rows that meet condition of other row

Tags: mysql

I want to ask how can I check all rows in one column (which is foreign key) and then 
if all that rows meet some condition then to get the result from it in MySQL.

For example I have three tables as follow

```
Products

ID   Price
1    70
2    20
3    55


Bill

ID  (others columns are not important)
100
200
300


ProductsBill

ID  BillID  ProductID
1   100     1
2   100     3
3   200     2
4   200     1
5   300     2
```

Now I want so select all BillsID where ALL products in that Bill has a price higher than 50, 
which in this case should return the Bill with ID 100 because only this bill contains products which price are higher than 50

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables, group by billid and set the condition in the having clause:

```
select 
  pb.billid
from productsbill pb inner join products p
on p.id = pb.productid
group by pb.billid
having min(p.price) > 50
```

Comment: Thank you forpas,
I have tried this 
select 
  pb.billid
from productsbill pb inner join products p
on p.id = pb.productid
where p.price > 50
group by pb.billid

and it not worked, What is difference between where and having clause?

Comment: The WHERE clause will return  all billids that have at least 1 price > 50. This is not what you want. When you get the min price for each billid then with the having clause you set the condition that the min price will be > 50. So all products have price > 50

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT BillID FROM ProductsBill WHERE BillID NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT pb.BillID FROM
    ProductsBill pb JOIN Products p on pb.ProductID = p.ID
    WHERE p.PRICE < 50
);
```

The subquery ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT pb.BillID FROM
        ProductsBill pb JOIN Products p on pb.ProductID = p.ID
        WHERE p.PRICE < 50
```

... selects all BillID's where there is at least one product with an associated price < 50. The outer query then selects all BillId's that are in the ProductBill table that do *not* have at least one product with an associated price < 50.